# Node.js library to read/write from Mongo by convention (e.g. findByEmailAndLogin)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, spring-data

Is there any node.js library which allows to perform mongo queries with a syntax similar to findByEmailAndLogin (Spring Data style). I found something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-find-by-whatever but it seems to work only for limited(single?) fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Mongoose (it's not clear from the question which method of connecting to Mongo do you use so it's hard to tell) then you can ad your own custom methods.

For example let's that you have this schema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  login: String,
});
```

You an add a custom method like this:

```
UserSchema.methods.findByEmailAndLogin = function findByEmailAndLogin (x, cb) {
  return this.model('User').find({$or: [{ email: x }, { login: x }]}, cb);
};
```

or something like that.

I assume that this is what you want by searching for email and login because googling for "findByEmailAndLogin" returns 0 results so it is not clear what you want it to be similar to.

Comment: This is not what I am asking for - this is how I normally do it. I was thinking more about something which will cover this with some abstraction that I don't have to implement it each time. So something like in https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-find-by-whatever but for bigger number of queries.